# Display info from api to html table

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem with an api , I've try  `console.log(response.[""0""].body`)  to get a respone on console , but it's not working .I need to take all those data from api in my table.

**This is my code:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   Js code

    var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    $.ajax({
     url: root + '/posts',
     method: 'GET',
     success: function(response) {
     console.log(response);
     }
     
    });
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    body.appendChild(table);
    table.setAttribute('id', 'mytable');
    var createrow = function(c1,c2){
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.appendChild(c1);
        row.setAttribute('class', 'row')
        row.appendChild(c2); 
    
        return row;
    }
    var createcell = function(value){
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.setAttribute('class', 'cell');
        cell.innerText=value;
        return cell;
    }
    
    
    table.appendChild(createrow(createcell('Mihaela'),createcell('11')))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made you an example using the new [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), written in vanilla JavaScript with zero dependencies.

```js
const root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

const asyncFetchPosts = async() => (
  fetch(`${root}/posts`)
  .then(res => res.json())
);


const start = async() => {
  const posts = await asyncFetchPosts();
  const tableHead = document.getElementById('myTableHead');
  const tableBody = document.getElementById('myTableBody');
  
  // Let's read all property keys from the first post
  // Array: [userId, id, title, body]
  const keys = Object.keys(posts[0]);

  // Add table head row
  const tableHeadRow = tableHead.insertRow(tableHead.rows.length);

  // Iteare over keys to create the header
  keys.forEach((key, i) => {    
    const newCell = tableHeadRow.insertCell(i);
    const newText = document.createTextNode(key);
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
  });
  
  // Iteare over all posts
  posts.forEach(post => {
    const newRow = tableBody.insertRow(tableBody.rows.length);
    
    // Now iterate over the keys for each post
    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
      const newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);
      const newText = document.createTextNode(post[key]);
      newCell.appendChild(newText);
    })
  });
}

// Call start
start();
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <thead id="myTableHead">
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How can i make it  for entire api , i mean body ,title , id etc .If you can give me more detail how i'll be greatefull . ty

Comment: @AndrewLennon I've updated my example, showing you how to iterate dynamically over the post properties. For various reasons, we only read the post `property keys` one time and then use it while iterating over all posts.

Comment: Ty i'm reallt gratefull !!

Answer (score 0):

Try using console.log(response[0].body)